# Android Server calls migrate to GZIP

Tags: android, networking, gzip, android-volley

We have an IOS and android apps whose are not using GZIP however we would like to change our server to user GZIP for reducing the traffic network.

Which is the best way to migrate API calls to use GZIP on mobiles?

I guess the previous version that does not have the GZIP will have problems.

am I right?

Comment: You mean reponse stream compressed? If so, just need to decompress it, then process the decompressed stream as normal

Comment: Yes, I know that. but what happens with the previous version that does not have that decompress process?

Comment: Of course the result will not be displayed correctly, for example, it can be "!$"$)%(#(@js" string :)

Comment: I know it, that´s what I´d like to know the best way to migrate it.  An option will be to add in the header a flag so the server will GZIP only the calls with that Flag, however not sure it is a clean way to solve the problem.

Comment: You mean server compressed by client's demand?

Comment: Yep, is that possible? if so,  is it a good practice?

Comment: I think it's OK for your internal use. Good practice? I don't know really, however, as you said "reducing the traffic network", then it is the most important reason, isn't it?

Comment: yep, it is the most important reason. Our users will be pleased if we reduce the amount of traffic.